# neo4j change visual settings in objects

Tags: python, neo4j, data-visualization

I'm visualizing pcap with neo4j and python.
I'm trying to change the color and size of objects in my graph by cli.
I have parsed the volume of traffic and im want object size to be set by it.
im looking for a way to change \ style the visual setting of objects.

I'm running community Neo4j Browser version: 3.2.20

Neo4j Server version: 3.5.6

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This might be useful: https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/#_styling_neo4j_browser_visualization

Comment: I have tried to use the py2neo API, found out there is stylesheet option where you put grass file